# Environment dependent CSV parse issue- Rails MacOSX vs Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, csv, heroku

Importing data from a CSV via file upload.  `csv.each_with_index` parses the same file differently in my local development environment and on Heroku (cedar):

```
# Sample CSV row:
# Steel Can,100,2.6,31,Steelco

csv = CSV.parse(infile, {:headers => true})
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  row = ???
end
```

Locally the row is read as an array containing a single long string:

```
row = ["Steel Can,100,2.6,31,Steelco"]
parse via: row[0].split(",")
# Seems weird CSV parser requires a split on a comma, but w/e
```

On Heroku the row is read correctly as an array containing multiple strings:

```
row = ["Steel Can","100","2.6","31","Steelco"]
parse via: row
```

For S&Gs I tried adding quotes around every field in the CSV, it resulted in an improperly formatted CSV error and I abandoned it.

**What's causing the same file to be parsed differently on the server?**

Comment: would you run 'puts RUBY_VERSION' in each environment

Comment: Ah :) Local is 1.8.7, remote is 1.9.2.  Will update and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Ruby 1.8.x, CSV is a completely different library than Ruby 1.9.2.

In Ruby 1.9.2, the CSV library is the Ruby 1.8 FasterCSV library.